# TypeError: Cannot read property 'create' of undefined. (sequelize, nodejs)

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js

When I try to send a post on localhost3000:/user/signup, I get this error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'create' of undefined

**Router**
routes/user.js is:

```
  const path = require('path');

const express = require('express');

const  userController= require('../controllers/user');

const router = express.Router();

router.post('/signup', userController.postSignup); 

module.exports = router;
```

**Controller**
and controller/user.js is:

```
const db = require('../models/');
const { User } = require('../models/user');

exports.postSignup = (req, res, next) => {
    const name = req.body.name;
    const email = req.body.email;
    const username = req.body.username;
    const password = req.body.password;
    const country = req.body.country;
    db.User.create({
        name: name,
        email: email,
        username: username,
        password: password,
        country: country
    })
    .then( result => {
        console.log(result);
    })
    .catch( err => {
        console.log(err);
    });
};
```

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: User.create instead of db.User.create

Answer (score 0):

Use `User.create()` and try with async/await syntax

```
exports.postSignup = async (req, res, next) => {
  const name = req.body.name;
  const email = req.body.email;
  const username = req.body.username;
  const password = req.body.password;
  const country = req.body.country;

  try {
    const user = await User.create({
      name: name,
      email: email,
      username: username,
      password: password,
      country: country
    })
    res.status(201).send(user)
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).send(err)
  }
};
```

It is more elegant than using promises.

Comment: Solved it myself, there was an issue with importing models. I was exporting modern as 'user'   and imported as User.